# Unix dat file reading script

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I have a dat file with 1000's of lines, need to cut few characters from each line ex: -c900-903. If this extracted length of character are not whitespaces, need to print whole line to new dat file. How can i do it in unix script?

I have tried this

```
while IFS=read -r line; do
characters= cut -c900-903
if [ -n $characters ]
then
echo "$line"
fi
done < $inputfile > $output file.
```

Comment: Do you mean that when the characters are all whitespace, they should be removed? Do you want to print the whole line to the other file, or just the characters that you've extracted? Please [edit] to explain more and show us an example of your input/desired output.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to move all lines with a minimal length to another file? Why move, if you also want to delete all lines with length < 10 ?

Comment: Need to move whole line if extracted length of character are not whitespaces, I tried below code                                                                               while IFS=read -r line; do
characters= cut -c900-903
if [ -n $characters ]
then
echo "$line"
fi
done < $inputfile > $output file.  But the above code is not working, It's writing the extracted characters into new file..

Answer (score 0):

After `IFS=` you need a space.
When you assign a value to the variable `characters`, you should avoid spaces.
With `characters="cut -c900-903"` you will assign a text to characters, not the result of a subcommand. Use `$(command)` for this.
The `cut` command will need some input to cut, use `echo "${line}"`.
Spaces are not empty, the `-n $characters` (what should have been `-n "$characters"` avoiding errors chan the var is empty) will be happy after seeing spaces.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   characters=$(echo "${line}"| cut -c900-903)
   if [ "${characters}" != "    " ]
   then
      echo "${line}"
   fi
done < $inputfile > $output_file
```

For large files this will become very slow due to the subcommands that need to be loaded in each loop. You can try other tools like `awk`, `grep` or `sed`.
Does the following work for you:

```
grep -vE "^.{899} {4}" ${inputfile}
```

Comment: Thanks... @Walter. Modified code worked for me. But It's taking around 10 minutes for 50000 records, i have a dat file with around 2 Lakhs(0.2 millions) of records - size 700 MB. I need to run this script through Autosys job, which in turn triggers another job on success... Is there any faster approach to do the same scenario to read the file and to get desired output as above?? I tried Awk but, got the error stating record is too large to read...(Each record is of around 5000 characters)...

Comment: Did you try the `grep -vE` ? Just from the commandline, without a loop and redirect the output to a file? Or test first with `head -10 ${inputfile} | grep ..`

Comment: With newer awk versions (nawk or better gawk) you do not have the recordlen limitation.

Comment: I tried to run grep on input_file from command line  to re-direct the output to new file. But didn't worked, got an error as "invalid option -E" ...         grep -vE "^.{899} {4}" input_file > output_file, input_file is of with 25 records.

Comment: perhaps you can try `egrep -v "^.{899} {4}" ${inputfile}` or try `sed '/^.\{899\} \{4\}/ d' ${inputfile}`